# PHPExcel download not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am trying to create a page that allows a user to download the contents of an SQL table, into an excel file.

Problem : When I open the excel file, it only contains random gibberish. An example -

```
PKQ=DG’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa
•(0ö¤±êØ–gúw{&i‰@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l
mð¥‘×ÁX¿(ÅÛü)¿’òF¹à¡;@1_æ»˜±Øc)j¢x/%ê…Eˆày¦
```

This is my code -

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$download="";
if (isset($_GET['surveyid'])) {
//Survey ID
$download = $_GET['surveyid'];
require_once('../Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$query="SELECT b.question_id as qid,
                a.question as ques,
                b.response as response,
                count(b.response) as cnt
          FROM v3_sai.survey_responses b 
          INNER JOIN v3_sai.survey_questions a 
             ON a.id = b.question_id 
                AND a.survey_id=".intval($download)."
          group by b.response, a.question
          order by b.question_id";
          var_dump($query);
$resultdl= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowcount=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl)){
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $row['qid']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowcount, $row['ques']); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowcount, $row['response']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowcount, $row['cnt']); 
$rowCount++; 
} 
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
die();
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Expires: 0");
?>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1> qid</h1>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1> ques</h1>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1> response</h1>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1> cnt</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl)){
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['qid']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['ques']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['response']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['cnt']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: Oh ye gods, accepted answer is to create html markup and pretend that it's an Excel file.... what is the world coming to?

Comment: Well it does work... None of the other solutions work :|

Comment: It does something completely different, that MS Excel is generous enough to work with.... and that may be adequate for your needs, but it doesn't actually _answer_ your question; and some more recent versions of Excel may complain about the discrepancy between file format and extension

Comment: Not to mention the syntax errors in `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc".xls");` and in `header("Pragma: no-cache");
("Expires: 0");`

Comment: how do I forced download this one?

Comment: Solution for this  add "ob_end_clean();" in download script  , note : start and end from the header this is the main solution , due to tmp memory observed that issue.

Answer (score 3):

If youre downloading an `xls` file (BIFF), use the `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5` Writer; if you're downloading an `.xlsx` file (OfficeOpenXML), use the `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007` Writer: **DON'T** mix and match... that's your problem. You're creating an .xlsx (OfficeOpenXML) file using the Excel2007 Writer, but setting the headers to tell the browser to expect an .xls (BIFF) file

Recommended headers for an .xls (BIFF) download are:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
```

Recommended headers for an .xlsx (OfficeOpenXML) download are:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
```

Note that `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`, may be treated as case-sensitive by browsers, so `Content-Type` is not the same as `Content-type`.... and I believe that may also give you problems

Comment: Error I get when doing this is - "Excel cannot open the file '01simple-1.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Comment: Excel still opens though

Comment: Some versions of Excel will complain about a file format that doesn't match the file extension.... that's why you should send the correct headings that match the file type you're creating: but it's unclear from your question whether you're seeing `PKQ=DG’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa
•(0ö¤±êØ–gúw{&i‰@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l
mð¥‘×ÁX¿(ÅÛü)¿’òF¹à¡;@1_æ»˜±Øc)j¢x/%ê…Eˆày¦` in the browser, or in the MS Excel when you open the file

Comment: Ah sorry to not make that clearer, I see that in excel! And specifically, I see it AFTER all the table data (So the actual functionality is working properly now, but the junk data I could do without)

Comment: If you see it _after_ the table data, then you're still echoing the table data (ie sending it to `php://output`) as well as the Excel filestream.... that's resulting in a completely corrupted file. When downloading a file to a browser, make sure you _don't_ output anything else at all, whether through echo/print or even simply spurious newline or space characters outside of the PHP tags.

Comment: A lot of people use [ob_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) immediately before the headers to ensure that no additional output can be sent to the browser, and a die() immediately after the save()

Comment: Note for future reference, that `junk data` as you call it is the actual Excel (OfficeOpenXML) filestream.... that is an actual Excel file to Excel; but because you have all the additional table data it's been echoed after that

Comment: I added ob_clean() just before the headers, now the excel opens without any issues, but the excel sheet itself is empty! :o

Comment: In that case, were you iterating through the database query resultset building html markup, and then iterating through it again to populate the PHPExcel object? If so, you shouldn't have been building the html markup in the first place... your code doesn't show that, but it would explain why the file had apparently "loaded", imported as html with the stream of `junk data` at the end; and unless you'd reset the resultset so that it looped again at the start (using [mysql_data_seek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)) then there would be no more rows to loop over...

Comment: ... so the PHPExcel worksheet would never have been populated, and so would be empty. Using the ob_clean() would eliminate the html markup from being sent to the php://output stream, so the Excel workbook would have been created cleanly as a real OfficeOpenXML file, but without any actual data

Comment: Here is the full code with nothing removed. http://codepad.org/ETVNQudd. I'm actually learning quite a bit from you, thank you!

Comment: You __are__ displaying a load of HTML, and not even populating the PHPExcel worksheet with data, so that certainly explains your problems

Comment: What would I need to change here? And the HTML is the page's own HTML. Containing a list of surveys, and allowing the user to choose one, which would then download its report.

Without ob_clean, it works with the Excel Filestream characters appearing at the end. With it, the page is blank (As you said, I am not actually sending it across). Could you please guide me towards a solution? :)

Answer (score 2):

I know i might be responding a bit late to this but none of the above worked for me. It's true using `ob_clean();` will remove any cached material so that it does not interfere with the returned headers + file content. What matters is where do you clean of the extra gibberish. So after days of scratching my head i've noticed that you need to `ob_clean();` right before the headers. If you do it somewhere else you will have the same problem. Here is a sample code that worked for me.

```
            ob_clean();
            $fileName = "Test.xlsx";
            # Output headers.
            header("Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/");
            header("Cache-Control: private");
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$fileName."'");
            // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
            // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
            header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
            header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
            header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
            # Output file.
            $return->save('php://output');
            die();
```

Comment: This, combined with @Mark Barker's answer about "DON'T mix and match" solution worked. ob_clean and die at the end made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and disable error reporting.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
$objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Tried this. No change :( Still gibberish

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem and finally found what was causing it.
Somewhere before `$objWriter->save('php://output')` is called the output buffer is being written to unintentionally. 
You can test this by `var_dump(ob_get_contents())` just before `$objWriter->save('php://output')`.

A quick fix would be to add ob_​start() at the beginning of the script and then `ob_​end_​clean()` just before `$objWriter->save('php://output')`but the perfect fix would be to find where the output buffer is being filled in.